# Countdown won't stop and start the game if needed players are online

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I am having this problem with my code. When i am the only one online the game will start normaly and the countdown will stop but when there are two or more players online the game wont start and the countdown begins at 120 wich should happend if only one player was online. Anyone that has an conclusion?

My code:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    if (timeUntilStart == 0) {
        if (!Game.canStart()) {
            if(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() <= 2) {
            plugin.restartCountdown();
            ChatUtilities.broadcast(ChatColor.RED + "Not enough players to start. Countdown will");
            ChatUtilities.broadcast(ChatColor.RED + "restart.");
            for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ENDERDRAGON_WINGS, 5, 1);
        }else{
            if(Game.canStart()) {
                if(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() >= 2) {
            Game.start();
                }
            }
            }
        }

    }


    boolean broadcast = false;

    for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        p.setLevel(timeUntilStart);

        if (timeUntilStart < 6  || timeUntilStart == 10 || timeUntilStart == 120 ||timeUntilStart == 60 || timeUntilStart == 30) {
            p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ORB_PICKUP, 5, 0);
            if (timeUntilStart == 0) p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ZOMBIE_INFECT , 5, 1);
            broadcast = true;
        }
    }


    if (broadcast) ChatUtilities.broadcast(String.valueOf(timeUntilStart) + " §3Seconds until the game starts!");
    {

    }





    timeUntilStart -= 1;
    if (timeUntilStart < 0) {timeUntilStart = 0;
    if(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() <= 2) {
        plugin.restartCountdown();

}else{
    if(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() >= 2) {

    Game.start();
}



}
     }
}
 }
```

Comment: `if(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() <= 2)  { plugin.restartCountdown(); }` - shouldn't this be `if (Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() <= 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (broadcast) ChatUtilities.broadcast(String.valueOf(timeUntilStart) + " §3Seconds until the game starts!");
{

}
```

What's that? Why did you put those {}?

```
if (timeUntilStart < 0) {timeUntilStart = 0;
if(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() <= 2) {
    plugin.restartCountdown();

 }else{
if(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() >= 2) {

Game.start();
}
```

it's not needed, because you're already starting the game when the timer reaches 0.

> but when there are two or more players online the game wont start and the countdown **begins at 120** wich should happend if only one player was online.

We can't help you with that, in your code there's nothing that does it.

> but when there are two or more players online the game wont start

Maybe it's an issue related to your Game.canStart() method.

Did you copy this code from Ben's tutorials? They're really bad. Poor Java knowledge and inefficient code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `yourInteger = Bukkit.getScheduler.sheduleSyncRepeatingTask`? You probably should.

For example if you were making a minigame and you wanted to start a countdown you would check if it's already counting down then call the countdown task as stated before IN A NEW METHOD, then inside the new method check to see if it is <= 0 not = 0 incase of errors. If it cannot start, use `Bukkit.getScheduler.cancelTask(yourInteger)`